# Jquery Validation for a single field

Tags: c#, jquery

My form is

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "CreateUser" ,id="createform"}))
 { 
  @Html.ValidationSummary();
<div class="field"><label>User Name*</label></div><input name="UserName" type="text" />
<div class="field"><label>Name</label></div><div class="field1"><input name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/><input name="Middlename" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" /><input name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" /></div>
<div class="field"><label>Email*</label></div><input name="Email" type="text" />
<div class="field"><label>Mobile*</label></div><div class="field2"><input name="CountryCode" type="text" placeholder="Country Code" /><input name="Mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" /></div>
<div class="field"><label>Language</label></div><input name="Language" type="text" />
<div class="field"><label>Expiry Date*</label></div><input name="Expiry" type="text" id="datepicker" />

<input id="send" class="subbtn" type="submit" value="Create"/>
```

How can I validate only user name field using jQuery?

Comment: Is it really asking so much that you read over your question and correct the obvious typos before posting?

Comment: Also, what kind of validation do you want? Your question is vague

Comment: i want to know how a single field is validating in a form using jqury

Answer (score 0):

if your need required field validator, you can use something like this(JS):

```
<input name="UserName" type="text" id="UN"/>

var textBox = document.getElementById('UN');
if(textBox=='')
   //your error message
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want make user name a mandatory field. If it is so you need to add following attribute to your user name input control:

```
<input name="UserName" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="User name field is required."/>
```

Also you need to configure unobtrusive validation here is the link how to do it: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#createform').submit(function(){
    var user_name = $('input:first').val();
    if(user_name == /*whatever you want to test*/){
     //doesn't pass test
     this.preventDefault();
     alert("Username error");
    } else {
     this.submit();
    }
  });

});
```